# Alt+Space cannot be remapped by PowerToys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, remapping, powertoys

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> seems to be a Windows default shortcut, and I wish to disable it because it interferes with the controls of a game I play. I did some research and came upon PowerToys, it seemed very useful and I tried remapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to Disable, and changed the PowerToys Run shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

However <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is still bringing up that little window at the top left corner of app windows. Searched around and nobody else seems to encounter this issue.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQ8W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will intercept the ALT+Space combination
from Windows and send it instead to the current process:

```
$!Space::SendPlay, #{Space}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)